# Android emulator has no internet connection on linux OS

Tags: linux, android-studio

Android emulator has no internet connection on linux OS.

- using Android Studio
- using Linux Operating System

Error is `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG`.

Changing dns server of local LAN/WLAN has no effect.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the comand line tool emulator to add dns-server option:

```
~/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -dns-server 8.8.8.8 -avd YourDeviceName
```

To list your created devices you can use:

```
~/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator -list-avds
```

See also:

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#dns